# Cent OS 7.2 Disk (df -h) 100% full but directory size (du -sch /* ) not

Tags: centos7, directory, du

```
[root@CentOS-72-64-minimal ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2        204G  202G     0 100% /
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G  1.6G   14G  10% /run
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1        488M  186M  277M  41% /boot
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0



[root@CentOS-72-64-minimal ~]# du -sch /*
0       /bin
183M    /boot
0       /dev
22M     /etc
836K    /home
4.0K    /installimage.conf
12K     /installimage.debug
0       /lib
0       /lib64
16K     /lost+found
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /opt
0       /proc
244M    /root
1.6G    /run
0       /sbin
4.0K    /srv
0       /sys
32K     /tmp
2.6G    /usr
6.1G    /var
11G     total

[root@CentOS-72-64-minimal ~]# df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md2       13565952 803442 12762510    6% /
devtmpfs        4057932    443  4057489    1% /dev
tmpfs           4063363      1  4063362    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           4063363    559  4062804    1% /run
tmpfs           4063363     13  4063350    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1         131072    344   130728    1% /boot
tmpfs           4063363      1  4063362    1% /run/user/0
```

please help me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if some process isn't holding open files on the filesystem:

```
sudo lsof +L1
```